# Function template specialization type - is it optional?

Tags: c++, templates

Is the `<const char*>` optional in below code? I found that g++ and clang compiles without it just fine.

```
template<typename T>
void debugRep2(T const& t) {
  std::cout << "debugRep(const T& t)\n";
}

template<>
void debugRep2<const char*>(const char* const& t) {
            //^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  std::cout << "const char*& t\n";
}

int main() {
  int n;
  int *pn = &n;
  debugRep2(n);
  debugRep2(pn);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The templated type is already specified at the function parameter and can be deduced by the compiler

```
template<>
void debugRep2<const char*>(const char* const& t) {
                         // ^^^^^^^^^^^ already present
    // ...
}
```

So yes, in this case it is optional.

---

In fact the common way to write that specialization would be

```
template<>
void debugRep2(const char* const& t) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: different question, but is it possible to specialize the tempalte like this: `template<> void debugRep2<const char*>(const int& t){}` ?

Comment: @tobi303 I don't think so, the parameter types would conflict in this case.

Comment: Do you know of any case when the templated type is obligatory?

Comment: @mike Some function template that uses `T` solely inside the body, e.g. a local variable definition would require an explicit template type definition.