# Why a template specialization cannot change the return type?

Tags: c++, templates

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38803903/function-template-specialization-type-is-it-optional/38803924?noredirect=1#comment64976852_38803924) I had to realize once more how little I know about templates. I can understand, that a template specialization like this

```
// A
template <typename T> void foo(T x){}
template <> void foo<double>(int x){}
```

cannot work (`error: template-id 'foo<double>' for 'void foo(int)' does not match any template declaration`). Not only would it make little sense, but also parameter deduction would have no chance to get the right `T`. However, I do not understand why it does not work for return types:

```
// B
template <typename T> int foo(T x){}  
template <> double foo<double>(double x){}
```

(similar error as above). Actually I dont have any particular use case at hand, but still I would be interested in how to choose a return type depending on `T`. As a workaround I found this:

```
// C 
template <typename T> struct foo { static int moo(T x){return x;} };
template <> struct foo<double> { static double moo(double x){return x;} };
```

So it is possible to choose the return type depening on `T`. However, I am still puzzled...

**What is the reason for `B` being not possible?**

Comment: None of your examples uses `T` as return type actually, what did you expect? Templates aren't your magic wand to break the syntax rules completely.

Comment: With template specialization, you can provide an alternative (specialized) *implementation* for the function template; you cannot change its prototype.

Comment: As other workaround, you have return type traits as in skypjack's example, or in your case, simply an overload: `double foo(double x);`

Comment: I think you are conceptually looking for an overload, rather than a specialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if strange, you may have

```
template <typename T>
void foo(int);

template <typename T>
char foo(int);
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/22237aaaad297385)

So your specialization would be ambiguous.

Comment: Compilers should reject that code with a _you shall not pass_ error (semi-cit.). :-)

Comment: @skypjack When the function templates with completely identical parameter lists have different `std::enable_if_t` return types so that for every `T`, `foo<T>` can refer to at most one of the overloads, this is actually a useful feature.

Comment: @hvd Well, right, I actually use it often indeed. I was just joking. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you can work around it either by using a template parameter for the return type or a traits class.
As an example:

```
#include<type_traits>

template<typename T>
T f() { return T{}; }

template<typename>
struct Traits;

template<>
struct Traits<int> {
    using ReturnType = char;
};

template<>
struct Traits<char> {
    using ReturnType = int;
};

template<typename T>
typename Traits<T>::ReturnType g() { return T{}; }

int main() {
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f<int>()), int>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(f<double>()), double>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g<int>()), char>::value, "!");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(g<char>()), int>::value, "!");
}
```

In the case of `g`, if parameters are deduced you have that two apparently identical calls have different return types.

That said, specializations don't allow the user to change the declaration of a function.
That's why you have to play with such a definition to have different return types for different template arguments.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Default template parameters

Your case "C" may be easily worked around with default template parameters:

```
template<typename T, typename U = int>
U foo(T x) {
    return x;
}

template<>
double foo<double, double>(double x) {
    return x;
}
```

Now `foo` may be used like a function with single template argument:

```
auto a = foo(5);
auto b = foo(1.0);
auto c = foo<short>(5);
```

### 2. Type map

Another approach is much uglier, but somewhat more universal. It will require you to enumerate all possible return types in one place, allowing you to choose any of those return types based on template parameter type. The crux of this solution is just a compile-time type map. It can be implemented variously using pairs, tuples, and `tuple_element`s, but let's stop on a minimalistic implementation:

```
struct last_key{};
struct last_value{};

template<typename key, typename k = last_key, typename v = last_value, typename ...pairs>
struct type_map {
    static_assert(sizeof...(pairs) % 2 == 0, "Last key does not have a value");
    using type = typename std::conditional<std::is_same<key, k>::value,
        v,
        typename type_map<key, pairs...>::type>::type;
};

template<typename key>
struct type_map<key> {
    using type = int;
};
```

The map "returns" value type for a given key type or `int` if key not found. Having the map, let's declare a return type which depends on a single template parameter:

```
template<typename key>
using return_type = typename type_map<key, double, double>::type;
```

And finally your example case "C" will again be solved by the only declaration of `foo`:

```
template<typename T>
auto foo(T x) -> return_type<T> {
    return x;
}
```

But if you want, you still may add specialization with different behavior, which will compile and work correctly:

```
// Specialization.
template<>
auto foo(double x) -> double {
    return x;
}
```

Now both with or without specialization, the following code:

```
auto a = foo(1);
auto b = foo(1.0);
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(a), int>::value << std::endl;
std::cout << std::is_same<decltype(b), double>::value << std::endl;
```

will print

```
1
1
```

Comment: With default template parameter and specialization, your `auto b = foo(1.0);` does not use the specialization, so type of `b` is `int`.